# How can I remove characters from a line in a text file without renaming the file?

Tags: string, powershell, random, cmd

I want to be able to take a file in a folder and write it to a text file in batch or PowerShell. The output in the text file should have FileName, NewFileName, DateModified. The FileName is what the file was named before it was ingested in a program and output. NewFileName is the name of the file that was output from the program and stored in the output folder.

The PowerShell script below is what I have used to get the name and date modified of the files to display in a text file.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path D:\Documents\Projects\Trans-Wrapping\TestOut\NewFiles\Audio\ -Recurse |
    Select-Object @{n='File'; e={$_.Name + "," + $_.LastWriteTime}} |
    Out-File "D:\Documents\Projects\Trans-Wrapping\TestOut\NewFiles\Audio\Log.txt"
Get-ChildItem -Path D:\Documents\Projects\Trans-Wrapping\TestOut\NewFiles\Video\ -Recurse |
    Select-Object @{n='File'; e={$_.Name + "," + $_.LastWriteTime}} |
    Out-File "D:\Documents\Projects\Trans-Wrapping\TestOut\NewFiles\Video\Log.txt"
```

However, the output I want is the original file name that was ingested.

FileName before ingested in program: Some_Name_file.mxf

NewFileName after ingested: *random_exactly_37_characters_**FileName.mxf**_random_exactly_11_characters*

The original file does not exist anymore, so I could have just added the path of that and said to write its name. So is there a way I can remove those 37 characters before the file name and the last 11 characters at the end of the filename and write that down on the same text file. I do not want to rename the NewFileName because it would change the date modified parameters.

Comment: Why don't you use CSV files instead of plain text. You could use `Get-ChildItem -Path D:\Documents\Projects\Trans-Wrapping\TestOut\NewFiles\Audio\ -Recurse | Select-Object Name , LastWriteTime | Export-Csv -Path "D:\Documents\Projects\Trans-Wrapping\TestOut\NewFiles\Audio\Log.csv" -NoTypeInformation`

Comment: I can use csv, but then how do i remove the 37 characters before and 11 characters after the name. Also what does -NoTypeInformation Do @Olaf

Comment: Please read the help for the cmdlet [Export-Csv](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/export-csv?view=powershell-5.1) to learn about it and about its parameters. You could even try to run the command with the parameter and once without and compare the results for yourself. If there are alwas exactly 37 charachters to remove you could use the substring method available for strings in Powershell. For example `'ArbitraryString_With some Cahrachters Keep This and forget the rest'.Substring(38, 9)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This assumes that the underscores and the file extension are included in what you want to remove, and you always want to remove 37 leading characters and 11 following characters. You can do this using the `Substring` property of your file name.

```
$audioFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path D:\Documents\Projects\Trans-Wrapping\TestOut\NewFiles\Audio\ -File -Recurse |
    Select-Object @{n='File';e={$_.Name.Substring(37,($_.Name.Length-37-11))}},LastWriteTime
$audioFiles | Export-Csv "D:\Documents\Projects\Trans-Wrapping\TestOut\NewFiles\Audio\Log.csv" -NoTypeInformation

$videoFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path D:\Documents\Projects\Trans-Wrapping\TestOut\NewFiles\Video\ -File -Recurse |
    Select-Object @{n='File';e={$_.Name.Substring(37,($_.Name.Length-37-11))}},LastWriteTime 
$videoFiles | Export-Csv "D:\Documents\Projects\Trans-Wrapping\TestOut\NewFiles\Video\Log.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Keep in mind that substring character indexes start at 0 and end at `Length-1`.

---

An alternative is to use the `-replace` operator, which uses regex for string matching.

```
$audioFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path D:\Documents\Projects\Trans-Wrapping\TestOut\NewFiles\Audio\ -File -Recurse |
    Select-Object @{n='File';e={$_.Name -replace '^.{37}(.*).{11}$','$1'}},LastWriteTime
$audioFiles | Export-Csv "D:\Documents\Projects\Trans-Wrapping\TestOut\NewFiles\Audio\Log.csv" -NoTypeInformation

$videoFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path D:\Documents\Projects\Trans-Wrapping\TestOut\NewFiles\Video\ -File -Recurse |
    Select-Object @{n='File';e={$_.Name -replace '^.{37}(.*).{11}$','$1'}},LastWriteTime
$videoFiles | Export-Csv "D:\Documents\Projects\Trans-Wrapping\TestOut\NewFiles\Video\Log.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

- The `.` matches any non-newline character.
- `{N}` matches the previous mechanism (`.` in this case) N times.
- `(.*)` is a capture group (`$1`) that matches any character until there are exactly 11 characters left.
- `^` denotes the beginning of the string.
- `$` denotes the end of string.

Essentially, the entire filename gets replaced with just the middle substring.

Comment: I tried both of these, the problem with this code is that it creates a new file with the name, not put all of it in a text file

Comment: what is the format of the data you want in the text file? In your example, you are outputting an object to the text file, which is ugly. Do you want a CSV output with a file column and file names listed underneath?

Comment: The output should be 

The name after the 37 start and 11 end of string is removed, The original FIle name, Date Modified all list down appending the list. It doesn't matter if is CSV or a normal txt file